# Trying to download traineddata files(Tesseract)

Tags: android, file, url, download, tesseract

i'm trying to download this file: tesseract-ocr-3.02.eng.tar.gz on android with the commands:

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
urlConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
urlConnection.connect();
```

from this url = "https://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/files/tesseract-ocr-3.02.eng.tar.gz"; and it is not working. It is throwing an UnknownHostExeception and the error is coming from the last command urlConnection.connect();

What can i do for fixing it and download the file?

Comment: u cant directly download file in this way..bcoz the above code will connect and open the url.

Comment: ok, how can i do it? Can you show me a code that is doing that(Downloading the above file and unzip to a folder)?

Comment: her shows good tut: http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/04/29/download-file-android-device-remote-server-custom-progressbar-showing-progress/